# Simple assembly code generates buffer overrun

Tags: c++, assembly, buffer-overrun

I am trying some assembly code to learn how it works but in my first example i faced with the buffer overrun exception. I am using VS2013 express edition and i am using c++ code to make the assembly code work by using extern "C" functionality. I tried to change some VS options but it did not work. What could be reason to give a buffer overrun exception while it is that much simple statement. Normally i build and executed without the mov statement.

Edit : **Just add a ret statement for the macro and the problem solved.**

This is assmbly part:

```
.586
.model flat,c
.data
.code

doit proc

mov eax, 8  
doit endp
end
```

and here it is c++ part:

```
extern "C" void doit();


void main()
{  

doit();

}
```

Comment: I do not see a ret statement. Does the macro endp generate it itself?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yeah it is generating a ret statement itself.

Comment: I don't really see how this program can cause buffer overrun, there *are* no buffers? On a (probably) unrelated note, you define your `main` function wrong, it must always be defined to return `int` (though you can skip the `return` statement and the compiler will issue an automatic `return 0;`).

Comment: Try saving the eax register before changing it and restoring it after, e.g. push eax, mov eax, 8, pop eax and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: No it does not make any difference.

Comment: @logic_cube The value in the `eax` register is considered to be the return value, since the function is declared to return `void` the C compiler simply doesn't care about it. However, since the compiler knows there will be no return value it *might* store something in the register, but I think `eax` is considered a scratch register in all cases anyway, so as noticed by the OP it doesn't matter.

Comment: @yekose Is this really your whole program? How do you build the assembler file? What happens if you fix the return type of `main`? If you run in the debugger, where in the code does it stop on your "buffer overflow"? Please add more details.

Comment: VS 2013 express, There is one cpp file which is the code above and one asm file which is configured to be compiled with the command line ml /c /Cx /coff "%(FullPath)" , and i both run it in the release and debug mode, it is giving the error in doit procedure, actually it has just one procedure and while it xor's the eax register and even i change the return type of main nothing differs, even if i remove mov eax,8 it does the same thing. I think it is about some another configuration of VS but i could not sort it out.

Comment: From the beginning @VladfromMoscow was right but i was thinking i did not need it but when i add a ret statement to doit macro problem totally solved.:)

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that the assembler procedure has no `ret` statement. So the behaviour of the program is undefined.:)